# Is it safe to use browser window.sessionStorage or ng libraries like ngx-webstorage in Angular 4

Tags: angular, github, npm, web-storage

I am trying to find the answers for, Which is best suitable way to use Session Storage in Angular 4 or later version like 5.

Currently project is using HTML5 window localStorage and sessionStorage. Should I use third party libraries like angular-2-local-storage or ngx-webstorage.

If yes, which one is best to use / more efficient compared to others ?

Please suggest.

Comment: Personally, I've always used local and session storage in angular. Third party libraries should be safe, but I suggest you to avoid storing sensible data on the front-end. Make a well-built back-end to store safely sensible data and in the front end store where you prefer just non-sensible or encrypted data (IDK what's your app situation, but normally in the front-end I just store JWT tokens)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be noted that the use of localStorage (or sessionStorage) is **absolutely neither safe nor proven**. Depending on the data you're storing, you could be creating significant vulnerabilities and/or liabilities. If your client is expecting security, build a proper back-end.

If you're looking for an opinion on the two libraries I would go with ngx-store, as the angular2-localstorage library is no longer maintained.

The decision to use a library vs. the native window.localStorage call depends, or course, on the specifics of your situation.

Comment: Apologies, I am only using window.sessionStorage not localStorage.

Comment: my App is big and client expects high end secure data in the flow app. in that case ? libraries or natives ?

Comment: sessionStorage is no safer. consider building a proper back-end. :)

Comment: @NickTirrell what did you mean by proper backend?

Answer (score 1):

Using browser localStorage and sessionStorage is safe and proven. So I would recommend to use browser features unless and until they are satisfying your need. And libraries like should be using browser local and session storage locally. Look for source code for this libraries.

Comment: my App is big and currently using window Session Storage. So question also is in terms of Efficiency, libraries like ngx-webstorage is better or window one is better ?

Comment: Please don't use the words 'localStorage' and 'safe' in such close proximity.

Answer (score 1):

If your use case requires simple use of Localstorage and sessionStorage then simply go to normal window's Local and session storage but if you need something in advance then you can go for third party packages.

But I would recommend to use window's one over third party package